# How to block/shut down click action for 1 second

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, preventdefault

I have some problem, i need to block/shut down some click action for some little time. What i'm trying to do is fire all actions after my click, but block this click when this actions is under procesing. So this is my code, thx for help:

```
carousel_controls_buttons.live('click', function(e){
    carousel_controls_buttons.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function(){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(xml).find("main_menu").each(function (){
           // some actions
        });
        carousel_controls_buttons.removeAttr('disabled');
    }, 450);
});
```

Comment: The way you are using `.live` is very odd. It might aswell be `.click` in that form, it won't handle dynamic elements properly unless the `carousel_controls_buttons` variable is updated when new elements are added, at which point you could bind the event there rather than using live.

Comment: Can I ask why you're trying to block in the first place?

Comment: Why not disable the button for one second instead?

Comment: You're preventing the default action too late, you have to do that from outside `setTimeout`.

Comment: Your code works as-is. What exactly is your question? It looks like you are asking how to do what your code is already doing. http://jsfiddle.net/m2QhK/1/

Answer (score 0):

I am presuming you are wanting something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    carousel_controls_buttons.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    setTimeout(function(){
        carousel_controls_buttons.removeAttr('disabled');
    }, 1000);

    carousel_controls_buttons.live('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $(xml).find("main_menu").each(function (){
        // some actions
        });
    });
});
```